# How to access "http://localhost" from a Docker container in Windows?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network, docker-container

I have a set of containers running in Windows 10 with Docker, this is the output of `docker-compose ps`:

```
> docker-compose ps
     Name                    Command               State                          Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
db_mysql          docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      3306/tcp
elk               /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c ...   Up      0.0.0.0:81->80/tcp
php71-fpm-nginx   /config/bootstrap.sh             Up      443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9001->9001/tcp
```

And this is the output of `docker inspect`:

```
> docker inspect php71-fpm-nginx
[
    {
        ...
            "NetworkMode": "anotherlampdocker_default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ],
                "9001/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "9001"
                    }
                ]
            },
        ...
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "/d/Development/www",
                "Destination": "/data/www",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            ...
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "b96cf4c0f2c17d65659c31982b9200a79cca6f1c214770d31938204c493a6720",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "443/tcp": null,
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ],
                "9001/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "9001"
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...
            "Networks": {
                "anotherlampdocker_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": [
                        "db_mysql:db",
                        "db_mysql:db_mysql"
                    ],
                    "Aliases": [
                        "php-fpm",
                        "248e8c254eee"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "de1e10b63e6e5050809af59ac4d26b7cb691afd5805d1cf7f0492c702814f34d",
                    "EndpointID": "ccec71967c6100c5a9f3ad82d82bbb2a371f77e12c493bf05bfd15f2d188ce00",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I am trying to access `http://localhost` but I can't. I've tried also using the container IP meaning `http://172.18.0.3` and doesn't work either.

When I say I can't it means the following message:

> This site can’t be reached
>   172.18.0.3 took too long to respond.

The same container works perfectly in Linux.

This is the content of `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
```

The ports from the container are mapped to the host in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  php-fpm:
    container_name: "php71-fpm-nginx"
    build: php-fpm
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 9001:9001
    environment:
        PHP_ERROR_REPORTING: 'E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE'
        STATUS_PAGE_ALLOWED_IP: '127.0.0.1'
    volumes:
        - D:\Development\www\:/data/www
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Have you mapped local port to docker container port?

Comment: @Rao yes, look at the edit on the OP

Comment: What happens if you curl http://localhost from inside the php/nginx container? You can get shell in container using `docker exec -it php71-fpm-nginx bash`

Comment: connecting to the container with localhost is not possible currently due to a bug in the windows 10 NAT stack.

Comment: @jmiraglia yes I can get shell into the container and this is the result of the CURL command: `[root@248e8c254eee /]# curl localhost
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:80; Connection refused`

Comment: @FalcoAlexander then if localhost can't be used what's the right way?

Comment: If you can shell into the container, can you see if nginx is up and running? 

You may want to try separating php and nginx into separate containers.

If you want, you can check out, my repo:  https://github.com/onlinespaces/docker-project-base. I am not an expert but this works for me.

Comment: @ScottCollier ohh that good really nice, I will give it a try, did you tried on Windows already?

Comment: Yes, I use it at work on a mac and on windows at home. The only issue that I had on Windows is that you interactive containers are not supported.

So, you can either do ```docker exec -it php-fpm bash``` as @jmiraglia stated above or you can connect via SSH and get a full shell. 

I prefer to SSH into it because I like to do everything inside the container to keep my Windows machine as clean as possible. I also like the pretty git information in the prompt which did not work when I used ```docker exec```.

Comment: @ScottCollier after clone the repository, rename the file `.env` and try the command `docker-compose build` it ends with the following error `ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: One or more build-args [DEFAULT_CHAR_SET COLLATION_SERVER CHAR_SET_SERVER] were not  consumed, failing build.`, what I did miss here?

Comment: @ReynierPM you can connect to the container either by its NAT IP (usually 172.* range) or externally from another computer with your "normal" IP

Comment: Sorry, I was working on the repo at the time and accidentally deleted some lines. You can download the new mysql/Dockerfile here:

https://github.com/onlinespaces/docker-project-base/blob/master/docker/mysql/Dockerfile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not open web page on port 8080 when start tomcat inside Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547203/not-open-web-page-on-port-8080-when-start-tomcat-inside-docker)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the docker machine IP and access the application: 
1. Using command `docker-machine` : `docker-machine ip`
2.or By login to the docker image which is created when you start the docker and getting the eth1 ip

Then try : [docker-machine ip]:[port]

Answer (score 0):

Try login to the php's container and check if the httpd process is running.

Use `docker-compose up` without -d should help you to see the log from container or use `docker-compose logs -f -t` after `docker-compose up -d`