# Not open web page on port 8080 when start tomcat inside Docker

Tags: windows, docker

On my local machine  Windows 10 (64 bit) I start docker  Toolbox. Then I  pull Tomcat image and run it like this:

```
docker run -it tomcat
```

It's success run.

```
31-Dec-2019 17:54:27.598 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
31-Dec-2019 17:54:28.849 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [1,246] ms
31-Dec-2019 17:54:28.851 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
31-Dec-2019 17:54:29.029 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [178] ms
31-Dec-2019 17:54:29.031 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs]
31-Dec-2019 17:54:29.128 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [90] ms
31-Dec-2019 17:54:29.129 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager]
31-Dec-2019 17:54:29.251 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [122] ms
31-Dec-2019 17:54:29.254 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples]
31-Dec-2019 17:54:30.480 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [1,226] ms
31-Dec-2019 17:54:30.499 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
31-Dec-2019 17:54:30.592 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
31-Dec-2019 17:54:30.621 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3185 ms
```

But when I open my browser and input

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

But page not found

Why?

Comment: (a) Because you don't have a `docker run -p` option; (b) since you're on Docker Toolbox, you need the `docker-machine ip` address, usually 192.168.99.100, and not `localhost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DavidMaze is right: there are simultaneously several issues (at least two, maybe more, see below) in the situation you describe, and each issue individually prevents a browser on the Windows host from accessing the web application deployed in the Docker container:

1. The web application needs to listen to the `0.0.0.0` special IP address (not `localhost`).
2. The `-p` (`--publish`) option of `docker run` is required. Let's say the web-app listens for port 8080, then to publish this exposed port to the 80 port on the host: `docker run -p 80:8080 […]` (but the two ports can be the same)
3. Finally as you use Docker Toolbox on Windows, you need to identify the Docker Machine IP where the web-app will be available (not `localhost`): if this information is not directly displayed by Docker Toolbox at startup, you may want to run: [`docker-machine ip dev`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/).

#### For more details

- Regarding items 1. 2., see also [How to convert a Spring-Boot web service into a Docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54269973/9164010)
- Regarding item 3., see e.g. [Can't access Spring Boot with my docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54224796/9164010)
- (albeit these threads deal with Spring-Boot, the details there are quite generic)

Comment: 1. docker-machine ip -> 192.168.99.100, 2. docker run -it -p 1234:8080 tomcat, 3.Open page on 192.168.99.100:1234. And now page open success